# integral support for a density function

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

$$f_{XYZ}(xyz)=ke^{-(x+y+z)}$$
$$ 0<x<y<z $$
I must find for which k this is a density function.
$$\int_{Rx}\int_{Ry}\int_{Rz} ke^{-(x+y+z)} dzdydx =1$$
$$k\int_{Rx}\int_{Ry}\int_{Rz} e^{-x}e^{-y}e^{-z} dzdydx =1$$
But I can't find which are supports of single variable.
I tried:
$$\int_0^y\int_0^z\int_0^\infty$$
But for this exercise I don't have solutions, so please help me.
This is a very stupid question, I know, I'm sorry.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $x$ can take any value in $(0,\infty)$; given $x$, $y$ can take any value in $(x,\infty)$; and given $x$ and $y$, $z$ can take any value in $(y,\infty)$. This suggests that you must compute
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_x^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}ke^{-x}e^{-y}e^{-z}\,dz\,dy\,dx=k\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\left[\int_x^{\infty}e^{-y}\left[\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{-z}\,dz\right]\,dy\right]\,dx.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I seriously think that yours is the right solution, I'm not sure but I think so.

Comment: or maybe not, in another exercise we had
$$f_{XYZ}(xyz)=k$$
with $ 0<x<y<z<1 $
and it was
$$k \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} \int_0^{1-y-z} dxdydz =1$$

Comment: @stat I assure you, the answer is correct.  Rather than trying to compare to a different exercise, just think through what I've done!  If you have a question on another exercise, feel free to ask it on this site and I'll be happy to try to explain it to you as well.

Comment: while with your method it would be:
x[0,1] y|x[x,1] z|yx[y,1]

Comment: Ok, I trust this one, thanks again Mr Peterson.

Comment: "Trust"? What the...

Comment: @Did sorry for my bad english.
I mean, thanks for the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try: $$k\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-\left(x+y+z\right)}dxdydz$$

Comment: maybe your is the right answer, which is your idea of the other one?